# What is correct "slowness" or "slowliness"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, is-it-a-word

I wrote email today and when I used word "slowliness" it got underlined by spell checker. I googled for slowliness vs slowness but couldn't find good answers.

Which one is correct? "slowness" or "slowliness"?

Comment: Before this post I had, to my recollection, never seen the word "slowliness".

Comment: When I googled "slowliness" I found two "add your own definition"-dictionaries that listed it as *rare* and that it's another word for *slowness*.  I couldn't find it in any curated dictionary.  I would therefore conclude that *slowness* is the preferred and generally accepted word here.  What did you find and what conclusions did you draw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Slowness" is correct.  "Slowliness" is not a word.